# Преобразование метода find в Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, строки, классы, методы, find

Задача:

Основная часть автомобильного государственного регистрационного номера состоит из 6 символов: трех букв и трех цифр. Сначала идет буква, затем 3 цифры и еще 2 буквы заканчивают запись. В качестве цифр могут использоваться любые цифры от 0 до 9, а в качестве букв только прописные буквы, обозначения которых присутствуют как в английском, так и в русском алфавите, т.е. только следующие символы: A, B, C, E, H, K, M, O, P, T, X, Y. Например, «P204BT» - правильный номер, а «X182Yx» и «ABC216» - нет. 
Определить, является ли введенный номер верным.

Есть такой код, преобразованный под Виндовс форму. Пишет что find не является членом класса (скриншот 1). Как можно исправить ошибку?

```
private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

        const String^ buk = "ABCEHKMOPTX";
        const String^ cif = "0123456789";

        String^ s = System::Convert::ToString(textBox1->Text);

        if (s->Length == 6 &&
            buk->find(s[0]) != -1 &&
            cif->find(s[1]) != -1 &&
            cif->find(s[2]) != -1 &&
            cif->find(s[3]) != -1 &&
            buk->find(s[4]) != -1 &&
            buk->find(s[5]) != -1)
        {
            String^ k = "Верный";
            textBox2->Text = System::Convert::ToString(k);
        }
        else
        {
            String^ k = "Неверный";
            textBox2->Text = System::Convert::ToString(k);
        }
    }
```

[image: ошибка]

[image: Сама форма выглядит так]

Comment: Среди методов класса [String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8#methods) нет метода find.

Comment: Как тогда лучше будет переписать? Может есть идеи...

Comment: Возможно Немного Ошибся. Тут find скорее всего выступает в роли функции, нежели метода